# Windows Phone 8.1 VibrationDevice doesn't stop vbration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I found a following issue of vibration device on Windows Phone 8.1 XAML application.

The code

```
var vibrationDevice = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
vibrationDevice.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
```

The first time when it's called, the vibration starts and doesn't stop until the next call. The following calls works correct - phone vibrates for short time and stops.

It reproduces on Lumia 920 at 100% calls and at Lumia 930 at 1% of calls.
It reproduces on WP 8.0 and WP 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the framework. What I use is to cancel it in a task after a delay which is the same as the vibration duration:

```
private const int DefaultVibrationDuration = 20;

if (this.EnableVibration)
{
    VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DefaultVibrationDuration));

    // Run task to cancel vibration (this is an error in phone framework where the vibration does
    // not stop after running the first time)
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(DefaultVibrationDuration);
        VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Cancel();
    });
}
```

Comment: I used it too, but I have received a report from tester, he wrote "time to time it doesn't help and phone vibrate until the following call" :(

Comment: Have you just used the `Cancel` method or have you wrapped the call in a new `Task` with ˙Task.Run˙? I have many, many users that use the small duration vibration every day, and have got no complain about this.

Comment: I don't wrap it in `Task.Run`, I use the following `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).ContinueWith(t => vibrationDevice.Cancel());`